# Int parameter in argv[]

Tags: c, casting, arguments, argv

So basically I got this project to school where we need to pass `int` parameters into `argv[]`. The project is in C.
We cannot use `string.h`

I tried to retype `argv[]` into `int` but since it is just a pointer it did not work.

Here is my code:

```
if(argv[1][0] == '1'){
            printf("Hodnota LEVEL je 1");

       } 
       else if(argv[1][0] == '2'){
           printf("Hodnota LEVEL je 2");

       }
```

As you can see I am currently checking if `argv[]` is equal to char '1' or '2' which is not what I want.

Only thing that comes to my mind is to replace '1' and '2' with some char variable and then recast it into `int`. After this process I can check if it is `int` 1 or `int` 2

Is there any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: Maybe use [`strtol()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) (prototype in `<stdlib.h>`): `int arg1 = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);`

Comment: You can convert a single string number into an int with `argv[1][0] - '0'`. If the number can have more than one digit then use a loop and simple maths to form the full integer.

Comment: nit: string.h is not a library.   It is a header.  Make sure you understand the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re not allowed to use the standard library, then you can do something like this:

```
int val = 0;
for ( char *p = argv[1]; *p != 0; p++ )
{
  val *= 10;
  val += *p - '0’;
}
```

The character encodings for decimal digits are guaranteed to be sequential, so subtracting the encoding for `'0'` gives you the equivalent integer value - e.g., `'1' - '0' == 1`, `'2' - '0' == 2`, etc.

You may want to add some sort of validation - if `argv[1] == "abcd"`, you’re going to get an interesting result.

If you *are* allowed to use the standard library, use `strtol` instead.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please explain, why is in that piece of code this line: `val *= 10;`

Comment: @DomHofman : for  if you have ‘21’ ther Val is first 2 then you multiply by 10 to get 20 and add 1. And continue if you have 3,4,… digits

Comment: Oh I get it now, thank you for explaining.

Comment: @DomHofman: Be aware, there was a pretty significant (and stupid) bug in the code I posted, I’ve just corrected it.  I was checking for `p == NULL`, which was incorrect - I’m not looking for a null pointer, I’m looking for a string terminator.  The correct check is in place now.